# SSRS stacked data bar with variable number of data points

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, stacked

We've been trying to come up with a flexible design for a stacked data bar in SSRS that would allow visualizing percentage of viewed video material in a 100% filled tablix column cell.

The goal is to clearly display the parts of a video clip that user has viewed. For example - we host a 1 hour long episode of a TV show, but users don't always watch entire episode from the beginning to end and we want to know which parts of the video they actually watched. Users may jump around - watch a little bit in the beginning, then skip to the middle and watch some more, then go to the end. The streaming video system we use provides detailed reports where viewing began and where it ended. Our job is to put that all the information into a concise, fixed length databar in order to quickly show how much of a given video clip a particular user has watched.

Here's the desired look of the report.

[image: Here's the desired look of the report]

In the first row, you'll see that the user has viewed about 20% of the video, then jumped to 49% and watched till 54% and then stopped. This resulted in 25% of the total length of video viewed.

Can this be achieved using stacked data bars? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: My for feel for "is this possible" is that it is. Have you got a query returning the relevant data developed yet? Sharing the output of this will assist in advice we give for the chart design.

Comment: I think a Range Bar chart is more suitable to use. It is the same with a gantt chart.

Comment: "In the first row, you'll see that the user has viewed about 20% of the video, then jumped to 49% and watched till 54% and then stopped." -  Its THAT kind of video huh? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a custom SSRS assembly that generates a bitmap image and returns it as a byte array, which is then used in the Image expression field.

If anyone is interested, the partial C# code used to generate image based on the viewed portions of the video is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SSRSExtensions
{
    public class ReportFunctions
    {
        public static Byte[] GetViewingRangeImage(String ranges, String imageFormatString, Single width, Single height, String backgroundColor, String foregroundColor, String separatorColor)
        {
            Byte[] retValue = null;

            ImageFormat imageFormat = GetImageFormat(imageFormatString);
            if (imageFormat != null)
            {
                ImageCodecInfo imageCodec = GetImageEncoderInfo(imageFormat);

                Bitmap bitmap = GetViewingRangeImageBitmap(ranges, width, height, backgroundColor, foregroundColor, separatorColor);

                using (EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
                {
                    using (EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L))
                    {
                        encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;

                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, imageFormat);

                            retValue = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The Image Expression is: ***=SSRSExtensions.ReportFunctions.GetViewingRangeImage(Fields!ViewingRange.Value, "PNG", 200, 25, "White", "#808080", "#bfbfbf")***

The actual ranges are specified in a comma separated string, like so: 
***0.000000-10.000000,20.000000-50.000000,90.000000-100.000000.***, where user watched first 10%, skipped to 20% and watched till 50%, then skipped to 90% and finished watching till the end.

This older blog post (https://blog.oraylis.de/2012/04/ssrs-custom-drawing-code/) talks about how to draw dynamic images and use them in reports. It uses inline VB. If you want to use C#, you'll have to create an external assembly, copy it to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server[SSRS INSTALL FOLDER]\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin folder and reference it in your report.

If anyone needs additional details on how to plug this all into SSRS report, let me know and I'll gladly help.